# How can I prove this inequality of the form $|f_1g_1-f_2g_2|\leq|f_1-f_2|$?

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove this inequality:

$$
\left|\frac{1}{\left(\left(x+a\right)^2+b\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\cdot\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt{\left(x+a\right)^2+b}\right)}{\cosh\left(\sqrt{\left(x+a\right)^2+b}\right)+c}
-
\frac{1}{\left(\left(x-a\right)^2+b\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\cdot\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^2+b}\right)}{\cosh\left(\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^2+b}\right)+c}\right|
\leq
\left|\frac{1}{\left(\left(x+a\right)^2+b\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{1}{\left(\left(x-a\right)^2+b\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|
$$

for all $x>0$ where $a,b,c>0$ are constants.

This could be more briefly expressed as:

$$\left|f\left(a,x\right)\cdot g\left(a,x\right)-f\left(-a,x\right)\cdot g\left(-a,x\right)\right|\leq \left|f\left(a,x\right)-f\left(-a,x\right)\right|,$$

where

$$f\left(a,x\right)=\frac{1}{\left(\left(x+a\right)^2+b\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, \qquad g\left(a,x\right)=\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt{\left(x+a\right)^2+b}\right)}{\cosh\left(\sqrt{\left(x+a\right)^2+b}\right)+c}.$$

After playing around with graphing software I am fairly convinced this inequality holds, but I can't figure out how to prove it. What makes it particularly tricky (to me) is that while $f(a,x)$ is increasing (in $x$), $g(a,x)$ is decreasing, so there is no general consistency as to which term (in the difference) is greater than the other.

Sorry if the inequality is wrong, or insanely difficult to show—I'm just wondering if there's an easy trick that I'm missing.

Comment: This might help.  Replace sinh and cosh by exp.  Good lick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this
(which is a standard grouping technique)
might be a start.

Simplifying the notation somewhat,
you want to show that

$|f(a)g(a)-f(-a) g(-a)|
\leq |f(a)-f(-a)|,
$

We have

$\begin{array}\\
|f(a)g(a)-f(-a) g(-a)|
&=|f(a)g(a)-f(a)g(-a)+f(a)g(-a)-f(-a) g(-a)|\\
&\le|f(a)g(a)-f(a)g(-a)|+|f(a)g(-a)-f(-a) g(-a)|\\
&\le |f(a)||g(a)-g(-a)|+|g(-a)||f(a)-f(-a)|\\
\end{array}
$

In your case,
$|g| < 1$.
This might also hold
for $f$
depending on the values of
$a$ and $b$.

More analysis of 
$f$ and $g$
might get useful results,
but I'll stop here.

Comment: Excellent. I'm not sure I can use this to prove my inequality, but I don't need to. My ultimate purpose is to use the dominated convergence theorem to move a limit inside an integral, and this will split the integral into two pieces that can be handled separately. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped. This sort of thing is the reason that I submit incomplete answers when I haven't completely solved the problem.